# This is why we puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, metapuzzles

*What kind of puzzle solver are you? Let’s map it out!*

## 1

> Nail item before each paper item (7) 
> After shooter’s return, receive big chunk (6) 
> Encourage bone disease (4) 
> Lost charge of gold and silver - lies! (4) 
> Theater costume’s warmth (4)

## 2

[image]

## 3

> *You’re getting close, but you have to get close to finish it off!* 
>  
> “Gotcha!” guy (6) 
> LSD part (3) 
> What to do with a dirt road (4) 
> *What’s left over when you get closer?* (3)

---

**Hint for 3:** (not part of the puzzle)

> _____ depression (5) 
>  Generic reptile (6) 
>  Oregon player (4)

Comment: We can see that each note has a point or a line. If we split these points and lines where there is a white note, we can obtain .- . ----. -.- .-. -, which is AE9KRT in morse code. I don't know if it is relevant in any mode... Maybe a key?

Comment: @Turvo You are putting clues in comments that everyone can see. Please look in the editing help for spoiler tags.

Comment: I’ve just realized that I should’ve included better hints for #3, judging by how much everyone was struggling on it. Sorry! Hopefully the edit will make things easier :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nail item before each paper item (7)

> **CLIPPER** = nail item, (paper)CLIP before PER (= each)

After shooter’s return, receive big chunk (6)

> **NUGGET** = big chunk, GUN< (= shooter) + GET (= receive)

Encourage bone disease (4)

> **SPUR** = encourage, = bone disease

Lost charge of gold and silver - lies! (4)

> **BULL** = lies, BULLION (gold and silver) - ION (charge)

Theater costume’s warmth (4)

> **HEAT** = warmth, hidden in tHEATer

These are all

> Singulars of NBA team names.

In #2, the composer's name "Gerri H. Dern"

> ...anagrams to RED HERRING.

M Oehm and Quuxplusone found the answers to #2:

> ROCKET, NET, JAZZ.

The hint to #3:

> _____ depression (5)
>  MANIC, which is MAGIC with one letter changed
>
>  Generic reptile (6)
>  LIZARD -> WIZARD
>
>  Oregon player (4)
>  DUCK (Oregon Ducks) -> BUCK

“Gotcha!” guy (6)

> This could be CAPTOR -> RAPTOR (from LeppyR64 in the comments)

LSD part (3)

> This is SIA (singer of the band LSD). With one change whis makes SIX, referring to the (Philadelphia Seventy) Sixers.

What to do with a dirt road (4)

> PAVE -> PACE (Pacers)

What’s left over when you get closer? (3)

> In the comments, arbitrahj pointed out that this could refer to the spare letters from each clue after the necessary changes. So with C, A and V left over this one would be the CAV(aliers).

Quuxplusone and Zimonze figured out the meta:

> When you place the cities on a map, they form letters.
>
>  #1 is Los Angeles (Clippers), Denver (Nuggets), San Antonio (Spurs), Chicago (Bulls) and Miami (Heat).
>  #2 is New York (Nets), Houston (Rockets) and Salt Lake City (Jazz).
>  #3 is Toronto (Raptors), Philadelphia (76ers), Indianapolis (Pacers) and Cleveland (Cavaliers).
>
>  [image: map]
>
>  The lines spell the letters MVP, answering the question:
>  *What kind of a puzzle solver are you?* – A **most valuable puzzle solver**!

Comment: If you split the morse code four dashes you get 'ENMMRKA' which is an anagram of 'MARKMEN' - not sure if that helps (you could also split them to make 'ENTORKA')

Comment: Captor -> Raptor?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Makes sense!

Comment: The ??? clue could be composed of the changed letters in the other clue. C_V, maybe CAV?

Comment: @arbitrahj I think you might be right.

Comment: Yes, that’s it! You got it, and answered the question perfectly too! The green check and bounty will be all yours... within a day, of course :)

Answer (score 14):

Partial answer

**The notes**

> The dots and dashes above and below the notes are `. -. ---- .-. -.- .-`. Ths is Morse code, but the letter separations are not in place. The only complete English word that can be made from that is `.-. --- -.-. -.- . -`, or **ROCKET**. This follows the theme jafe has spotted: The Houston Rockets are an NBA team.
>
>  There are half and quarter notes, fifteen in total. They form a Baconian cipher with I/J and U/V treated as the same letter. The half notes are B, the quarter notes are A. (The ♩=65 is a hint: 65 is the ASCII code of A.) This decodes to **NET**. (Brooklyn Nets)
>
>  The notes are just a scale, but some of them have a flat symbol. Again, jafe has found that these are the notes of the F minor key. That is a literal key: It can be used as a Vigenère key on the title, which yields: "Now You Has Blank". Hm.

Answer (score 8):

Building very slightly on [M Oehm's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/80930/3896), the third word hidden in Part 2 is

> **JAZZ**, because if you take the key (FMINOR) and Vigenère it into the title of the song, you get (literally) "Now You Has Blank", which is a reference to the Cole Porter standard "[Now You Has Jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_You_Has_Jazz)." And of course **JAZZ** fits the theme of NBA team names.

For part 3, I'm stumped, but some ideas might include:

"LSD part"

> **SUN**, via extremely obscure song title "Lucid Sun Divine" by some Spotify group named Mary Pranksters (no relation to [Mary Prankster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Prankster)). I highly doubt this.

---

> Somehow a reference to either **LAKE**(?) Shore Drive in Chicago, or pounds/shillings/pence. *waves hands vaguely*

---

The list of remaining possible words is still pretty long, even assuming there wouldn't be a twist at the end (which I bet there is). It's probably not going to be a "name the ones that are missing" kind of thing. But for the record:

> Atlanta HAWKs
>  Boston CELTICs
>  Charlotte BOBCATs
>  Cleveland CAVALIERs
>  Dallas MAVERICKs
>  Detroit PISTONs
>  Golden State WARRIORs
>  Indiana PACERs
>  Los Angeles LAKERs
>  Memphis GRIZZLY(ie)s
>  Milwaukee BUCKs
>  Minnesota TIMBERWOLF(ve)s
>  New Orleans HORNETs
>  New York KNICKs
>  Oklahoma City THUNDER
>  Orlando MAGIC
>  Philadelphia SIXERs
>  Phoenix SUNs
>  Portland TRAIL BLAZERs
>  Sacramento KINGs
>  Toronto RAPTORs
>  Washington WIZARDs

I am fairly confident that the next step (besides making any headway on Part 3) will be to

> **"map it out"**; that is, map the states or cities identified so far and see whether it makes a suggestive picture. Those cities are:
>  Los Angeles (CA), Denver (CO), San Antonio (TX), Chicago (IL), Miami (FL), Houston (TX), Brooklyn (NY), (Salt Lake City) UT.

Answer (score 6):

Based on everyone else's findings and the flavourtext *let's map it out*,

> I plotted the locations of the NBA teams for each part and they very likely spell the final answer (??? (3)) of **MVP** as [arbitrahj's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/80958/49783) suggests. The question *What kind of puzzle solver are you?* supports this.

Part 1

> [image: M]
>
>  LA, Denver, San Antonio, Chicago, Miami

Part 2

> [image: V]
>
>  Utah, Houston, Brooklyn

Part 3

> No idea, 3 places don't make a recognizable *P*. I fiddled with the possible solutions based on number of letter clues but nothing really works.

Comment: Well, the numbers of letters restrict the answer, but none of them really fit.

Comment: Also I should clarify that the fourth clue in #3 is purely part of that puzzle, not the meta

Answer (score 5):

Wild partial guesses for #3:

“Gotcha!” guy (6)

> **WIZARD** (magic trick, gotcha?)

LSD part (3)

> **SUN** (Orange Sunshine is one popular type)

What to do with a dirt road (4)

> **PACE** (Pacing in angst at "what to do?",pace at which you drive?)

??? (3)

> **MVP** This doesn't line up with my guesses, but the map could spell out **M** from part 1, **V** from part 2, and **P** from part 3, and the final clue could be the authors vote for 2019 NBA MVP *and* complete the letter P.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my attempt on the first one:

Nail item before each paper item (7)

> Stapler

After shooter’s return, receive big chunk (6)

> Reward

Encourage bone disease (4)

> Soda (?)

Lost charge of gold and silver - lies! (4)

> Bond (chemical bonds?)

Theater costume’s warmth (4)

> Coat

Comment: The first part is clues in the style of a "cryptic crossword." See https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/0/solve-cryptic-crosswords/

Comment: @Quuxplusone Thank you for the reference! I'm new to this